# What design logic to use with linked ViewLists

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

There is a dictionary with three keys: 'Animals', 'Birds' and 'Fish'.

The main dialog has two List views. The left view `viewA` displays the list of the keys mentioned above. 
When one of its items is clicked the right view `viewB` displays the list of the species.

The question is how to manage `viewB`'s display... Let's say the user clicks 'Animals': `listB` goes ahead and builds a brand new list of QListWidgetItem for every animal in a list. Then the user clicks 'Birds'. What should I do with already built `viewB`'s "animal" items? Should I hide them? (hiding "Animals" items (instead of deleting) would allow me unhide them later when 'Animals' is clicked again (makes total sense if ListItems are heavy on graphics: thumbs, icons and etc. If a list of animals is 1000+ there will be a noticeable difference between rebuilding the ListItems from scratch and unhiding the ones that were build on a last click).
Another approach I see is to user `viewB.clear()` every time `viewA`'s item is clicked. So the `listB` items are rebuilt every time `listA` item is clicked. But as I have mentioned with a long list of items it could be really slow. What logic to implement in situation like this?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)        

        self.viewA=QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.viewA.addItems(elements.keys())
        self.viewA.itemClicked.connect(self.aClicked)
        self.viewB=QtGui.QListWidget()   

        layout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        layout.addWidget(self.viewB)
        self.show()

    def aClicked(self, item):
        key='%s'%item.text()
        values=elements.get(key)
        items=[QtGui.QListWidgetItem(val) for val in values]
        result=[self.viewB.addItem(item) for item in items]

elements={'Animals':['Bison','Panther','Elephant'],'Birds':['Duck','Hawk','Pigeon'],'Fish':['Shark','Salmon','Piranha']}
window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single model for both views: QListView and QTableView:
[image]

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}

class DataModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.modelDict={}    
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)   

    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 4

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        column=index.column()

        if role==QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole: return self.modelDict.get(str(index.data().toString()))

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if column==0:
                return key
            else:
                return self.modelDict.get(key).get(column)  

    def addItem(self, itemName=None, column=0):
        totalItems=self.rowCount()+1
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems, column)
        if not itemName:            itemName='Item %s'%self.rowCount()
        self.items.append(itemName)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def buildItems(self):
        for key in self.modelDict:
            index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
            self.addItem(key) 

class ProxyTableModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProxyTableModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return QtCore.QVariant(int(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter))
            return QtCore.QVariant(int(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter))
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation==QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if column==1:
                return QtCore.QVariant("Species 1")
            elif column==2:
                return QtCore.QVariant("Species 2")
            elif column==3:
                return QtCore.QVariant("Species 3")

        return QtCore.QVariant(int(column + 1))

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)   

        self.dataModel=DataModel()
        self.dataModel.modelDict=elements
        self.dataModel.buildItems() 

        self.proxyModel=ProxyTableModel()
        self.proxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)    
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.dataModel)

        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.dataModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick) 

        self.viewB=QtGui.QTableView()         
        self.viewB.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.viewB.setColumnHidden(0,True)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewB)    
        self.show()

    def onClick(self):
        index=self.viewA.currentIndex()
        key=self.dataModel.data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)  
        value=self.dataModel.data(index, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole)        
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegExp('%s'%key)
        print 'onClick(): key: %s'%type('%s'%key)

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [Model-View](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/modelview.html) approach instead.

You'll have two models: *KeysModel* and *ValuesModel* inherited from `QAbstractListModel` or `QStringListModel`. Two views `QTableView`: *KeysView* and *ValuesView*. And one proxy model `QSortFilterProxyModel` *ProxyModel* which will help you to show values filtered by a key in ValuesView.

When an item in KeysView is selected just assign a new filter to *ProxyModel* and values in *ValuesView* will be changed.

Comment: Please use my example code to illustrate your idea. It is hard to grasp the concept without seeing how it would need to be put together. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sputnix, please read the documentation on Model/View programming, that @Ezee linked to in his answer. It's much easier to "grasp the concept", after having researched it, rather than having someone do the work for you!

Comment: The example I've posted is only 22 lines long. How long it would take to edit it to illustrate the concept? This forum is not only about pointing to docs.

Comment: I find it is much easier to learn the programming concept AFTER the concept was implemented in a code.

Comment: @Zero-Sixty-Nine:The example code posted in my question is an `example` code I wrote purposely to go along with the question. It wasn't copied/pasted from a "real" production code. No one is asked to do the work for someone else. But to illustrate the concept.

Comment: `QAbstractListModel` is covered in `Rapid GUI Programming with Python and QT` book starting from page 490. It is in "Advance GUI Programming" section of the book in "Advanced Model/View Programming" chapter. It takes 34 pages for the author of this book to go through the concept. Do you really think that what Ezee posted a comment not the answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

On the other class [`QColumnView`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcolumnview.html) it can design hierarchy of data. Try read document it.

Comment: Great! Terrific! Thanks! That was very helpful! Using `QColumnView` as keyword I can now google it all day long!